# Displaying image in web view

Tags: ios

i try to display image in my web view background, but i got little blue rectangle and an interrogation mark inside. My code is this:

```
NSString *myDescriptionHTML = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<html> \n"
                                   "<head> \n"
                                   "<style type=\"text/css\"> \n"
                                   "body {font-family:helvetica; font-size:12;}\n"
                                   "h2 {font-family:Times new roman;color: #105870}"
                                   "</style> \n"
                                   "</head> \n"
                                   "<body><img src=\"background.png\" /><h2>Nom station</h2>%@<h2>Adresse</h2>%@<h2>Tél</h2>%@<h2>Sens de circulation</h2>%@<h2>Voie</h2>%@<h2>Station de lavage</h2>%@<h2>Commerce</h2>%@<h2>Distance</h2>%@<h2>Types de carburants</h2>%@</body>\n"
                                   "</html>",leNomDeLaStation,adresseDeLaStation,telDeLaStation,circulationDeLaStation,voieDeLaStation,lavageDeLaStation,commerceDeLaStation,distanceDeLaStation,typesDeCarburantsDeLaStation];
    [webView loadHTMLString:myDescriptionHTML baseURL:nil];
```

All my text is shown correctly except the `background.png`. Thanx for help :)

**EDIT :**
i have tried this :

```
NSString* basePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:basePath];
    NSString *myDescriptionHTML = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<html> \n"
                                   "<head> \n"
                                   "<style type=\"text/css\"> \n"
                                   "body {font-family:helvetica; font-size:12;}\n"
                                   "h2 {font-family:Times new roman;color: #105870}"
                                   "</style> \n"
                                   "</head> \n"
                                   "<body><img src=\"background.png\" /><h2>Nom station</h2>%@<h2>Adresse</h2>%@<h2>Tél</h2>%@<h2>Sens de circulation</h2>%@<h2>Voie</h2>%@<h2>Station de lavage</h2>%@<h2>Commerce</h2>%@<h2>Distance</h2>%@<h2>Types de carburants</h2>%@</body>\n"
                                   "</html>",leNomDeLaStation,adresseDeLaStation,telDeLaStation,circulationDeLaStation,voieDeLaStation,lavageDeLaStation,commerceDeLaStation,distanceDeLaStation,typesDeCarburantsDeLaStation];
    [webView loadHTMLString:myDescriptionHTML baseURL:url];
```

Always i got the interrogation mark there :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i solved my issue, i have forgot the : `fileURLWithPath:path` method
my code is this for any one who have problem with that :

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath];
    NSURL *baseURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
    NSString *myDescriptionHTML = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<html> \n"
                                   "<head> \n"
                                   "<style type=\"text/css\"> \n"
                                   "body {font-family:helvetica; font-size:12;}\n"
                                   "h2 {font-family:Times new roman;color: #105870}"
                                   "</style> \n"
                                   "</head> \n"
                                   "<body><img src=\"background.png\" /><h2>Nom station</h2>%@<h2>Adresse</h2>%@<h2>Tél</h2>%@<h2>Sens de circulation</h2>%@<h2>Voie</h2>%@<h2>Station de lavage</h2>%@<h2>Commerce</h2>%@<h2>Distance</h2>%@<h2>Types de carburants</h2>%@</body>\n"
                                   "</html>",leNomDeLaStation,adresseDeLaStation,telDeLaStation,circulationDeLaStation,voieDeLaStation,lavageDeLaStation,commerceDeLaStation,distanceDeLaStation,typesDeCarburantsDeLaStation];
    [webView loadHTMLString:myDescriptionHTML baseURL:baseURL];
```

Comment: hey, this was exactly what I suggested to you in the first place! :-)

Answer (score 3):

You need specifying the correct `baseURL` in:

```
[webView loadHTMLString:myDescriptionHTML baseURL:nil];
```

otherwise the web view will not know where to look for you "relative" uris (the ones that do not start with http://)

Try this:

```
NSString* basePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath];
[webView loadHTMLString:myDescriptionHTML baseURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:basePath]];
```

EDIT: double check that you included `background.png` in the resources of your project and that the file name is correct.

Comment: i think i don't need to, i use the web view only for displaying formatted text and i didn't need to navigate so that i puted `nil`

Comment: You are showing a png: `<img src=\"background.png\"`, without the baseURL it will not be found.

Comment: i try your suggestions but i got always the interrogation mark and the picture is not displayed, please take a look at my EDIT :)